# mysql&php - Cannot execute Stored Procedure twice

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHandTypes()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Codemst WHERE code LIKE "HT%" AND dep > 0;
END$$

$result = mysql("CALL GetHandTypes()");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
```

It's work well. but When I try twice, It returns nothing.

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL GetHandTypes()");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
print_r($row);

$result = mysql_query("CALL GetHandTypes()");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
print_r($row); //null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to close the SQL connection after the first call, try using mysqli_query instead. See: (Comment: rogier 10-Apr-2008 01:55 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php )